# How to make expandable list Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to make one expandable list with level 1 and level 2, Normally level 1 list should display and when click on Level 1 list item item then Level 2 will open left side.
Please guide me how to do this.

[image]

I read so many tutorials but all are expending the list level2 down/ not left or right side,. Please guide me. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please guide me, if anybody have exact answer...

Comment: @CommonsWare, can you help me plesae..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems an interesting hack. I'm implementing something similar too, my be you should start from [here](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/expanding-listview-items/) from where i started basically. It gives you some ideas for what we are trying to implement.BTW that's the blog from the developer at the famous ANY.Do app which has that functionality.